# Difficulty with Copy as PDF in Mathematica 10.0.2.0

Tags: export, output-formatting

I just installed Mathematica 10.0.2.0 on my Mac and I find that I can no longer use the Copy as PDF commands to copy a Mathematica graphic and paste it into a powerpoint presentation.  When I do this the fonts in the graphic as rendered by powerpoint are huge and ugly. I have always been able to do this with earlier versions of Mathematica.  What has happened with 10.0.2.0?

Comment: A known bug I'm afraid. I am closing this question as a duplicate of an earlier post about this problem.  If you feel that your problem is *not* the same let me know and I shall reopen.

Comment: When you find a bug like this, it's best to report it directly to [Wolfram support](http://www.wolfram.com/support/).  Maybe if more people report it they'll prioritize it.